# What could be the namespace value for this xml

Tags: python, xml

`<connect:ConnectorsStatus xmlns:cdesc="exa:com.exalead.mercury.component.config.descriptor" xmlns:connect="exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10" xmlns:bee="exa:exa.bee" xmlns:config="exa:exa.bee.config"> <connect:ConnectorStatus connectorName="quasar_vpminstance" managed="true" connectorServer="java0" status="idle" classId="com.exalead.papi.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseConnector" runtime="java" papiServerType="consolidationServer"> <connect:PerBuildGroupStatus buildGroup="bg_search" activeDocumentsCount="0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalPartialUpdates="0" totalIndexedDocuments="0"/> <connect:PerBuildGroupStatus buildGroup="bg_ndt_search" activeDocumentsCount="0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalPartialUpdates="0" totalIndexedDocuments="0"/> <connect:PerConsolidationServerStatus consolidationServer="cs0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalConsolidatedDocuments="981214"/> <connect:previousScan> <connect:ScanStatus aborted="false" time="1669" startTime="1676960680503" endTime="1676960682172" scannedObjects="86" pushedObjects="86" deletedObjects="0" scanRetries="0"> <connect:specificMeasures/> </connect:ScanStatus> </connect:previousScan>be`

I want to use xpath function in my python code so it is expecting namespace too

Comment: `xmlns` tag means xml namespace

Comment: "I want to use xpath function in my python code" - OK. What is the actual problem? Where is your Python code? Note that only the `connect` namespace prefix is actually used in the XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML format looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connect:ConnectorsStatus xmlns:cdesc="exa:com.exalead.mercury.component.config.descriptor" xmlns:connect="exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10" xmlns:bee="exa:exa.bee" xmlns:config="exa:exa.bee.config">
  <connect:ConnectorStatus connectorName="quasar_vpminstance" managed="true" connectorServer="java0" status="idle" classId="com.exalead.papi.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseConnector" runtime="java" papiServerType="consolidationServer">
  <connect:PerBuildGroupStatus buildGroup="bg_search" activeDocumentsCount="0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalPartialUpdates="0" totalIndexedDocuments="0" />
  <connect:PerBuildGroupStatus buildGroup="bg_ndt_search" activeDocumentsCount="0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalPartialUpdates="0" totalIndexedDocuments="0" />
  <connect:PerConsolidationServerStatus consolidationServer="cs0" totalAdds="0" totalReplaces="0" totalDeletes="0" totalFailedDeletes="0" totalConsolidatedDocuments="981214" />
  <connect:previousScan>
    <connect:ScanStatus aborted="false" time="1669" startTime="1676960680503" endTime="1676960682172" scannedObjects="86" pushedObjects="86" deletedObjects="0" scanRetries="0">
      <connect:specificMeasures />
    </connect:ScanStatus>
  </connect:previousScan>be</connect:ConnectorStatus>
</connect:ConnectorsStatus>
```

And than you parse it with `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("connect.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag)
```

Output:

```
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}ConnectorsStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}ConnectorStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}PerBuildGroupStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}PerBuildGroupStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}PerConsolidationServerStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}previousScan
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}ScanStatus
{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}specificMeasures
```

So the relevant namespace what you search is:
**{exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10}** for the prefix `<connect:...` of the tags you find the relation under root; xmlns:`connect`="exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10"

Answer (score 0):

The namespace values for this XML are:

```xml
xmlns:cdesc="exa:com.exalead.mercury.component.config.descriptor"
xmlns:connect="exa:com.exalead.mercury.mami.connect.v10"
xmlns:bee="exa:exa.bee"
xmlns:config="exa:exa.bee.config"
```